# change media refresh image size with jquery

Tags: javascript, image, media, slide, image-size

```
function getItemWidth(){
    var slide_wi = 976;

    var window_width = $(window).width();

    if(window_width < 350){
        slide_wi = 300;
    }else if(window_width <= 568){
        slide_wi = 458;
    }else if(window_width <= 800){
        slide_wi = 746;
    }else if(window_width >= 1152){
        slide_wi = 976;
    }
    return slide_wi;
} ;
```

The problem with this size not refress change media for ex. iphone landsace and potratie

Answer (score 0):

Use function `onorientationchange`

```
window.onorientationchange  = function(){
    //Your Code 
}
```

Also to detect `landscape mode` or `potrait mode`, you can try this

```
var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
if(screenWidth>screenHeight)
{
    alert('landscape mode');
}
else
{
    alert('potrait mode');
}
```

Comment: http://64.85.165.53/demo/perfusionline/site/ it's responsive site pls check the ipadpeek.com

Comment: It can be done using `media` in `css`. Refer http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ . Also you can change `css` according to your `device screen`.